# How to accept all commits from a certain date

Tags: phabricator

I reinstalled Phabricator in my project. So I have a lot of commits to audit.
Is there a way to accept all commits from a certain date ? I would like to clean Phabricator in order to keep only last commits (per instance : last 2 weeks).

Answer (score 1):

Accept? No. Delete? Yes.

`./bin/audit` from the command-line